# How to intersect two sf objects?

Tags: r, r-sf

I have downloaded two .gdb files from here:

- Buildings shapes from [here](https://cosmos.surrey.ca/geo_ref/Images/OpenDataArchives/buildings_gdb.zip)
- Lots in the city from [here](https://cosmos.surrey.ca/geo_ref/Images/OpenDataArchives/Lots_GDB.zip)

I saved both folders into data folder and unziped them

```
library(sf)

lots <- st_read("data/Lots_GDB/lots.gdb",layer= "lot")
lots <-st_transform(st_cast(lots , "MULTIPOLYGON"), "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

buildings <- st_read("data/buildings_gdb/buildings.gdb",layer= "buildings")
buildings <-st_transform(st_cast(buildings , "MULTIPOLYGON"), "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84") %>%  select( FACILITYID,FACILITY_TYPE, STATUS)
```

What I would like to obtain:

1. I would like to leave only polygons from object lots that do not have inside them polygons from building objects ( ie I want lots with no buildings)
2. same thing , but also get only lots that do have buildings inside them.

I used `st_intersection()` to overlap two objects

```
lots_building<- st_intersection(lots, buildings)
```

And then plot it on teh map:

```
ggmap() +
  geom_sf(data= lots_building,  alpha=0.9, inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

But somehow `lots_building` does not seem to be the right feature to achieve the task.

Comment: Hi! Can you add more details on what's the problem and the desired output?

Comment: thank you, updated : I would like to leave only polygons from object lots that do not have inside them polygons from building objects ( ie I want lots with no buildings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried many things, but this one is the only thing that worked:

```
diffPoly <-lots[lengths(st_intersects(lots,buildings))==0,]
```

Comment: If it works, I think that's perfectly valid code

Comment: Original code did not work for me (st_intersection part)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The st_intersection code is used to compute the geometric intersection between lots and buildings. If you need to filter the POLYGON(s) (in lots) that intersect no POLYGON (in building), then I think this solution works.

Comment: when I run st_intersection(lots, buildings), no polygons are removed. although not all intersect. I want to obtain both versions: polygons that do and don't intersect ( or at least one of them- cause if I know lots that contain buildings, I can filter other lots that dont using polygons ids).